# Using mockjax - how do I add data to my simple highcharts chart and the drill down charts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts, drilldown, mockjax

I've looked through many, many stackoverflow examples and I need a simpler example.  I just want to connect my fake mockjax array data to my chart and also when I drill down into the columns.
Can anyone explain a simple and clear way to do it?  I'm new to highcharts.

http://jsfiddle.net/cgelinas78/CPZtw/8/

```
 $.getScript("https://raw.github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/master/jquery.mockjax.js", function(){
  $.mockjax({
          url: '/restful/fortune',
          responseText: {
            status: 'success',
              data: [20,50,45]
          } 
     });



$.getJSON('/restful/fortune', function(data) {
  $.each(data.data, function(i, value){
     var arr = JSON.parse([value])
          //alert(arr);

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['Jan-Mar', 'Apr-May', 'June-Aug', 'Sept-Oct', 'Nov-Dec'],
            ddcategories = ['invoice1', 'invoice2', 'invoice3','invoice4', 'invoice5', 'invoice6','invoice7'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [{
                    y: arr, 
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'MSIE versions',
                        categories: ddcategories,
                        data: [value],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: value,
                    color: colors[1],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Firefox versions',
                        categories: ddcategories,
                        data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                        color: colors[1]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 11.94,
                    color: colors[2],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Chrome versions',
                        categories: ddcategories,
                        data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                        color: colors[2]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 7.15,
                    color: colors[3],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Safari versions',
                        categories: ddcategories,
                        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                        color: colors[3]
                    }
                }, {
                    y: 2.14,
                    color: colors[4],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Opera versions',
                        categories: ddcategories,
                        data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                        color: colors[4]
                    }
                }];

        function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
            chart.series[0].remove(false);
            chart.addSeries({
                name: name,
                data: data,
                color: color || 'white'
            }, false);
            chart.redraw();
        }

        var chart = $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total expenses'},
                    labels: {
                     formatter: function() {
                        return '$' + this.value;
                    }
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function() {
                                var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                                if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                    setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
                                } else { // restore
                                    setChart(name, categories, data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: colors[0],
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '$' + this.y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var point = this.point,
                        s = this.x +':<b>'+ '$' + this.y +' USD</b><br/>';
                    if (point.drilldown) {
                        s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                    } else {
                        s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: name,
                data: data,
                color: 'white'
            }],
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            }
        })
        .highcharts(); // return chart
    });
});
 });
```